# Convert SQL query to Doctrine code

Tags: mysql, doctrine

How can I write this SQL query to Doctrine 1.2 query?

```
SELECT * FROM homes 
    WHERE published = 1 
    AND
    (
     LOWER(country) LIKE '$search%' 
     OR 
     LOWER(city) LIKE '$search%'
     OR
     LOWER(area) LIKE '$search%'
    )
```

**EDIT**

This is my actuall query. The example above was an simplified version. I just want to now how can I combine multiple WHERE together

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('h.*,c.*')
                        ->from('Homes h')
                        ->where('h.published = ?',1)
                        ->addWhere('LOWER(c.printable_name) LIKE ?', $search . "%")
                        ->orWhere('LOWER(h.city) LIKE ?', $search . "%")
                        ->orWhere('LOWER(h.area) LIKE ?', $search. "%")
                        ->orWhere('LOWER(h.name) LIKE ?', $search. "%")

                        ->leftJoin('h.Countries c');
```

Comment: Why do you need to `LOWER` fields explicitly? With default collations (the `ci` ones) mysql `LIKE` is case-insensitive.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error message? Did you know that LIKE is case-insesitive?

Comment: I am using UTF-8 and utf_general_ci without LOWER() I don't get case insensitive results

Comment: Hey do the above query works fine for single quote search text also eample($string = "testin'g")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the script that worked was:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('h.*,c.*')
                        ->from('Homes h')
                        ->where('h.published = ?',1)
                        ->andWhere('LOWER(c.printable_name) LIKE ? OR LOWER(h.city) LIKE ? OR LOWER(h.area) LIKE ? OR LOWER(h.name) LIKE ?', array($search . "%",$search . "%",$search . "%",$search . "%"))
                        ->leftJoin('h.Countries c');
```

I don't know thought if this is the best way to write it.